# Proof verification: Differentiation norm inequality

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, derivatives, inequality

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a differentiable application, $M > 0$ and $p > 1.$ If $\left \| f(x) - f(y) \right \| \leq M \left \| x - y \right \|^p $, for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, show that $\left \| f'(x) \right \| \leq M,$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, with $\left \| f'(x) \right \| = \sup_{|u| = 1}\{\left \| f'(x)u \right \|\}$.

My attempt was:

> Let $(h_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \left \| h_k \right \|= 0$ and, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $h_k \neq 0$. Since $f$ is differentiable, one can write $f(x + h_k) - f(x) = f'(x)h_{k} + r(h_k)$, where $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{\left \| r(h_k)\right \|}{\left \| h_k \right \|} = 0.$$ Thus, by hypothesis, $\left \| f'(x)h_k - r(h_k) \right \| \leq M\left \| h_k \right \|^p.$ Dividing this inequality by $\left \| h_k \right \|$, we have $\left \| f'(x)\frac{h_k}{\left \| h_k \right \|} - \frac{r(h_k)}{\left \| h_k \right \|} \right \| \leq M\left \| h_k \right \|^{p-1}.$ Taking the limit $k \to \infty $ on both sides, and using that every limited sequence has a convergent subsequence, exists $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{h_k}{\left \| h_k \right \|}$, it is true that $$\left \| f'(x)u \right \| \leq 0$$ and, since $(h_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\left \| f'(x) \right \| = 0 < M.$

It fells wrong, but I did not found any mistakes. Could anyone see if I'm right and, if not, provide a better answer? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just a small detail: you're missing norm signs inside $\sup\{ f'(x)u\}$

Comment: So you proved that $\|f'(x)\|=0$? what if $n=1$ and $f(x) = Mx^p$.